# Charlieplexing buttons gives additional outputs

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi-zero

I want to check if button is pushed using charlieplexing. For testing I've used 19 buttons. Connected them exactly like in this image, but with 4 buttons in each segment, with 5 segments (5 diodes): [image]

I've created this code:

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
pins = [5, 6, 13, 19, 26]
GPIO.setup(pins, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)
outputs = [[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0]]

while True:
        for pin in pins:
                GPIO.setup(pin, GPIO.OUT)
                GPIO.output(pin, GPIO.LOW)
                segment = pins.index(pin)
                pinsTemp = list(pins)
                pinsTemp.remove(pin)
                for pinTemp in pinsTemp:
                        button = pinsTemp.index(pinTemp)
                        if GPIO.input(pinTemp) == GPIO.LOW:
                                outputs[segment][button] = 1;
                        else:
                                outputs[segment][button] = 0;
                GPIO.setup(pin, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)
        print outputs;
        time.sleep(0.1);
```

Works fine when I'm pushing only one button, but after pushing two of them, I'm getting a response that four buttons are pushed. Example:

Pushed `S1` and `S2`.

Output: `[[0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 1, 1]]`.

Pushed `S1` and `S3`.

Output: `[[0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0, 1]]`

I've already tried using HIGH for detection as well as LOW (in both cases tried reversing diodes). Same results. For diodes I'm using 1N4148. Is it something to do with my connections or my code is bad? Or is there any better solution?

Answer (score 0):

When you "remove" from a list, you get a new list with new indices.
But you don't have to make temp list.
I could try something like that:

```
while True:
    for segment, pin in enumerate(pins):
        GPIO.setup(pin, GPIO.OUT)
        GPIO.output(pin, GPIO.LOW)
        for idx, button in enumerate(pins):
            if idx==segment:
                continue
            if GPIO.input(button) == GPIO.LOW:
                outputs[segment][idx] = 1
            else:
                outputs[segment][idx] = 0
        GPIO.setup(pin, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)
    print(outputs)
    time.sleep(0.1)
```

btw, the type of diode you're using won't change anything. ☺

Comment: Yeah, it's more like it, but with your code i need to use array with 5 arrays with 5 buttons, even though I'm using 5 segments with **4** buttons. You've removed part of code which was making 4-element list from 5-element list. Now, when it's trying to set outputs[0][4] it can't becouse it doesn't exist. Whats more: it doesn't work. The same problem still occurs. Yeah, it looks better, so I thank you for that but it's still not functional